# C & bash redirection processus communication

Tags: c, bash

look at this bash :

```
mkfifo fifo
./processA <fifo | processB >fifo
```

In my process A, i generate a file which is send by process B. Then I want to process the result of processB.

So in A I just send info to B with printfs into std out. Then I create a thread who just read(stdin). After creating this thread, I send infos to B via printf.

I do not understand why this whole sh block. The read never recieive anything. Why? the two process are tested and work fine separatly. The whole sh also work perfectly (dont block) if I dont read (but then I cant process B output).

Can somebody explain me what i am understanding wrong?
Sorry for my approximative English. I am also intersted by your clean solution if you have one (but it would prefer understanding why this one is not working).

//edit 
Here is the main (process A):

```
//managing some arguments threatment, constructing object...


   pthread_t thread;//creation of the thread supposed to read

  if(pthread_create(&thread, NULL,IsKhacToolKit::threadRead, solver) != 0) {
    fprintf(stderr,"\nSomething went wrong while creating Reader thread\n" );
  }
  solver->generateDimacFile();//printing to stdout


  pthread_exit(0);
}
```

the function executed by the thread is just supposed to read stdin and printing into stderr the string obtened (for now). Nothing is printed in stderr right now.

generateDimacFile print a char* into stdout (and flush(stdout) at the end) that processB use. The process B is that one: http://www.labri.fr/perso/lsimon/glucose/

here ise the function executed by the thread now :

```
char* satResult=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)* solutionSize);
for (int i=0; i<2; i++){
read(0, satResult, solutionSize );
fprintf(stderr, "\n%s\n", satResult);
}
DEBUGFLAG("Getting result from glucose");
```

Ok so now thanks to Maxim Egorushkin, I discovered that the first read dont block, but the next one block using that bash instead:

```
./processA <fifo | stdbuf -o0 ./processB >fifo
```

and if I use that one :

```
stdbuf -o0 ./processA <fifo | stdbuf -o0 ./processB >fifo
```

Most of the time I can read twice whitout blocking (some time it block). I still can't read 3 times. I dont understand why it change anything because I flush stdout in generateDimacFile.

Look at what's actually printed when it dont block(reading twice) in stderr:

```
c
c This is glucose 4.0 --  based on MiniSAT (Many thanks to MiniSAT team)
c



c This is glucose 4.0 --  based on MiniSAT (Many thanks to MiniSAT team)
c

c Reading from standard input... Use '--help' for help.
s to MiniSAT team)
c
```

The coresponding expected result:

```
c
c This is glucose 4.0 --  based on MiniSAT (Many thanks to MiniSAT team)
c
c Reading from standard input... Use '--help' for help.
c |                                                                                                       |
s UNSATISFIABLE
```

Comment: maybe share your code?

Comment: sorry but I'm really having difficulty in understanding which process is sending to whom

Comment: Why do you think the read blocks?  Are you expecting to see something on your tty?

Comment: I think read block because when I remove it it terminate. I am expecting the stder to be containing the result of process B which is not the case –

Comment: `stderr` does not get redirected in your command line, I am not sure why you write into it. Write into `stdout`.

Comment: sorry, i didnt mention i redirect stderr of A into a file for debug purpose

Answer (score 4):

You have a potentially blocking race condition.  If the processB needs to read a large amount of data before it produces anything, then it is possible that processA will be data starved before it produces enough data.  Once that happens, there's a deadlock.  Or, if processA never generates any data until it reads something, then both processes will just sit there.  It really depends on what processA and processB are doing.

If the processes are sufficiently simple, what you are doing should work.  For instance:

```
$ cat a.sh
#!/bin/sh 

echo "$$"

while read line; do echo $(($line + 1 )); echo $$ read: $line >&2; sleep 1; done
$ ./a.sh < fifo | ./a.sh > fifo
26385 read: 26384
26384 read: 26385
26385 read: 26386
26384 read: 26385
26385 read: 26386
26384 read: 26387
26385 read: 26388
26384 read: 26387
^C
```

Comment: But i use a thread to read, so for me, the thread listen while the main send to processB. When process B terminate (and it always do, its a famous sat solver) the thead should finally recieve in stdin something and proceed.

Comment: @JuanPepito Is processB getting enough data?  Add some diagnostics to your programs so you can get some visibility in to what they are doing.

Comment: yep, i actually print a lot of debuging message into stdr, so i know that every time the generatedimac ouput is correct. Also, if i remove the read and just pipe A into B i Get the right result every time printed in terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Using `|` or `>` in `bash` makes the process block-buffered, so that it does not output anything until the buffer is full or `fflush` is invoked.

Try disabling all buffering with `stdbuf -o0 ./processA <fifo | stdbuf -o0 processB >fifo`.

---

`stderr` does not get redirected in your command line, I am not sure why you write into it. Write into `stdout`.

Another issue is that

```
read(0, satResult, solutionSize);
fprintf(stderr, "\n%s\n", satResult);
```

is incorrect, `satResult` is not zero-terminated and the errors are not handled. A fixL

```
ssize_t r = read(0, satResult, solutionSize);
if(r > 0)
    fwrite(satResult, r, 1, stdout);
else
    // Handle read error.
```

Comment: I fflush at the end of generateDimacFile()

Comment: Ok thanks  indeed now the first read dont block, but the nexts ones does

Comment: @JuanPepito `stderr` does not get redirected in your command line, I am not sure why you mention it.

Comment: I didnt not mention (to simplify)but i redirect A stderr into a file in the bash for debugging purpose. I replaced my way of reading whit yours, and now it block at first read

Comment: @JuanPepito You may like to post complete examples that can be used to replicate your observations. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Since it need to finish it before saturday. I will focuse on another solution (since I dont have the knowledge to resolve such a problem) and then trying to understand this case later. I will try to usen popen() for now, which will allow me to remove the bash. I welcome any advices